# Prove $f$, satisfying $\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|\le K\left|x-y\right|^{\alpha}$, is constant. Proof strategy.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\alpha>1, K>0$ and let $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ satisfy $$\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|\le K\left|x-y\right|^{\alpha}, \forall x,y\in [0,1].$$ Prove $f$ is constant.

What I basically need is a proof strategy. I have an attempt:

Let us look at $\lim_\limits{x\to y}|f(x)-f(y)|=K\lim_\limits{x\to y}|x-y|^{\alpha}$. Since $\lim_\limits{x\to y}|x-y|=0$ and since $\alpha >1, K>0,$ then from some point that is not $0$, $K|x-y|^{\alpha}<|x-y|\to 0$. (How do I explain it more formally?).

That is, when $x\to y$, $|f(x)-f(y)|$ tends to $0$ more quickly than $|x-y|$ does. That is $\lim_\limits{x\to y}\left|{f(x)-f(y)\over x-y}\right|=0$ everywhere, dragging $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y \in [0,1] \Rightarrow  \displaystyle \lim_{x\to y} \left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right| \leq \displaystyle \lim_{x\to y}K|x-y|^{\alpha-1}\Rightarrow |f'(y)| = 0 \Rightarrow f'(y) = 0 \Rightarrow f = C$

Comment: How did you conclude that $|f'(y)|=0$?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't assume differentiability, then let $|f(x)-f(y)| \gt \epsilon \gt 0$
If $x_1,\dots ,x_n$ are numbers dividing the segment $[x,y]$ into $n+1$ equal segments then we have
$$|f(x)-f(y)| = |f(x)-f(x_1)+f(x_1)-f(x_2)+f(x_2) \dots -f(x_n)+f(x_n)-f(y)|$$
$$\le |f(x)-f(x_1)|+|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|+\dots +|f(x_n)-f(y)| \le (n+1)k\frac{|x-y|^\alpha}{(n+1)^\alpha}$$
If we take $n$ large enough we get $|f(x)-f(y)| \lt \epsilon$ which is a contradiction.